# Redirect logs from a jar to different file.

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

My project which produces XYZ.jar uses sl4j logging framework. The client consuming the jar is free to use any logging framework (like log4j or java logging etc).

I want the logs from XYZ.jar to come in a different file. How do I request the clien to configure the logs such that I get all logs from XYZ.jar to a different file XYZ.logs?

Comment: Maybe bundle configuration files for slf4j, log4j, and JUL with your jar distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking for here. If the client using your library is free to use whatever logging framework they want (which is good!), then they are also free to configure that logging framework however they want. You can "request" they put the logs for your library in a separate file just by asking nicely in your documentation.

If you want to make it easy for them to do so, make sure that you use loggers with a common prefix so it's easy to configure (you're probably doing this anyway if you have your classes in a package named for your product and use the default logger-based-on-class-name convention), and then provide sample configuration files in a variety of popular logging frameworks that shows how to save logs for your loggers to a separate file.